# Does the product rule $D(f\cdot g)(a) = Df(a)g(a) + f(a)Dg(a)$ hold for arbitrary normed vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I was wondering if the following result holds in general:

**Conjecture:** Let $V$ be a normed vector space over the field $K$ where $K$ accepts a norm $|\cdot |_K$, and let the functions $f:V\rightarrow K$ and $g:V\rightarrow K$ be differentiable at $a\in V$, then $(f\cdot g):V\rightarrow K$ is differentiable at $a\in V$ and
$$D(f\cdot g)(a) = Df(a)g(a) + f(a)Dg(a).$$

---

The conjecture holds, for instance, for functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, yet all the proofs I've seen of this restricted version of the theorem do not naturally generalize to normed vector spaces.

Comment: Finite dimensional Vector spaces are smooth manifolds no? You should be able to define derivations on them quite easily with vector fields.

Comment: But some of the best normed vector spaces aren’t fd.

Comment: You probably want your vector space to be complete so that you can take limits.

Comment: @CameronWilliams well the norm defines a metric which in turn allows us to take limits.

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. what do you mean by a derivation?

Comment: Sure, but you can have a normed vector space that isn't complete. It's a hop, skip, and jump away, but definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: What definition of a derivative do you have in mind here?

Comment: @Leo derivation over a field $K$ is a linear map that satisfies the product rule (Leibniz rule)

Comment: There are all sorts of theorems about derivatives that are only true when the spaces are complete, both the vector space and the field $K$. A prominent example is the mean value theorem. I strongly suggest you explore the case where both are complete before trying to expand to cases where they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $f(a+h) = f(a)+o(1)$ as $h\to0$.
It follows that
\begin{align*}
f(a+h)g(a+h)-g(a)f(a) &= f(a+h)\big(g(a+h)-g(a)\big)+g(a)\big(f(a+h)-f(a)\big) \\
&=
\big(f(a)+o(1)\big)\big(\operatorname{d}g(a)(h)+o(\|h\|)\big)+g(a)\big(\operatorname{d}f(a)(h)+o(\|h\|)\big) \\
&=f(a)\operatorname{d}g(a)(h) + g(a)\operatorname{d}f(a)(h)+o(\|h\|), \qquad h\to 0, 
\end{align*}
where the last equality follows from $\forall h \in V, |\operatorname{d}g(a)(h)| \le \|\operatorname{d}g(a)\|_{\operatorname{op}} \|h\|$.
By definition, this means that $fg$ is differentiable at $a$ with differential that satisfies
\begin{equation}
\forall h \in V, \qquad \operatorname{d}(fg)(a)(h) = f(a)\operatorname{d}g(a)(h) + g(a) \operatorname{d}f(a)(h) \;.
\end{equation}